# How to publish a package to NPM and Bower without git tag conflict?

Tags: npm, bower

I want to publish a package to Bower and NPM with the same version numbers. Lets' say my `package.json` and `bower.json` have version `0.0.0` and I do `npm version patch' then when I do`bower version patch` I get patch already exist error:

```
Command failed: fatal: tag 'v0.0.1' already exists
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, found the answer very quickly

Using [mversion](https://github.com/mikaelbr/mversion)

```
npm install -g mversion
mversion patch
```